# Django modeform choose date

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm doing a to-do web app and I want user to input deadline and I have DateTimeField for it, but user can write whatever they want, but I want them to choose a legit date.
models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

forms:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Add new task...'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

views:

```
def TaskView(request):
    tasklist = Task.objects.all()
    tasks = Task.objects.order_by('uploaded')
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    context = {
        'tastlist': tasklist,
        'tasks': tasks,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "pages/index.html", context)
```

[image: output of the code]

Comment: Perhaps you might find this package useful [django-datetime-widget2](https://pypi.org/project/django-datetime-widget2/).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yeah but I want to do it without a package

Comment: Then you would need some javascript solution of your own. If you see even html does not exactly have an input type for datetime (that works on all modern browsers, some have it).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no I found solution in Django documentation, but it's kind of complicated and it will take some time to understand it

Comment: Indeed Django does not provide direct way to implement datetime widget. Instead of installing a new package I have split it into two fields - a DateField and a TimeField and later I have combined them into a datetime:

datetime_object = datetime.datetime.combine(date, time, timezone)
datetime_object = datetime_object + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=3000)

Adding a timezone or miliseconds is not needed, but it certain cases might be useful.